# Is it wrong using {{}} in AngualrJS directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how my code looks like:

```
<a href class="item" ng-repeat="area in subAreas"
    ng-click="house.cityId='{{ area.id }}';house.cityType='{{ area.type }}';loadMainList(house)">
       {{ area.name }}
</a>
```

But when I click this link on page and it's not working. There's no error message found in console, just no response. I inspected the element in Chrome, and the value passed correctly.

Finally, I tried to use the real values instead of `{{...}}` syntax, just for standard usage, like this `ng-click="house.cityId=area.id;house.cityType=area.type;loadMainList(house)"`, the miracle happened, it worked. But this makes me confused as well.

Can anyone help explain what's the difference between these two usages? Or is it wrong using `{{}}` in AngularJS directives? I'm just a beginner in AngualarJS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you do not need {{}} inside ng-click.

Comment: `ng-click` already evaluates the content-string as an expression. So you don't need to tell to the framework that this is an expression as you would do with `{{}}`

Comment: Is that wrong using {{}} in angular directives?